# How to remove empty strings from array elemnets

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-of-loop

Here I am Taking a string data and converting it into array elements but it is getting an empty array at last of all array elements and I am not be able to remove them easily.Please help.

```js
let string_Data = `01226,Grover Cleveland,Anna,Uganda,Crucial Ltd,Tested Mutual B.V,Calvin Coolidge,
    77110,John F. Kennedy,hora,Bosnia Herzegovina,Formal,Papal Corporation,Franklin Roosevelt,
    29552,Lyndon B. Johnson,Margaret,Palau,Summaries Holdings Inc,Customize,Rutherford B. Hayes,`;

let making_Array = csv => {
  var data = [];

  for (let dataAry of csv.split('\n')) {

    data.push(dataAry.split(','));
  }
  return data;

}
console.log(making_Array(string_Data));
```

Comment: you have `,` at the end of each line, so there's an empty string after the last item.

Comment: Why your data has `,` at the end of each line? It seems like there is a column missing

Comment: since it is csv data and it is separated by comma's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manipulating arrays, you can prepare the string before being split.

```js
let string_Data = `01226,Grover Cleveland,Anna,Uganda,Crucial Ltd,Tested Mutual B.V,Calvin Coolidge,
    77110,John F. Kennedy,hora,Bosnia Herzegovina,Formal,Papal Corporation,Franklin Roosevelt,
    29552,Lyndon B. Johnson,Margaret,Palau,Summaries Holdings Inc,Customize,Rutherford B. Hayes,`;

let making_Array = csv => {
  var data = [];

  for (let dataAry of csv.split('\n')) {
    // 1. trim both ends of the line for white space, tab, etc.
    // 2. remove any last trailing comma
    // 3. split using comma separator
    data.push(dataAry.trim().replace(/,$/, '').split(','));
  }
  return data;

}
console.log(making_Array(string_Data));
```

---

FWIW the entire function can be streamlined, and enhanced like this:

```js
let header = ['id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6'];

let string_Data = `01226,Grover Cleveland,Anna,Uganda,Crucial Ltd,Tested Mutual B.V,Calvin Coolidge,
    77110,John F. Kennedy,hora,Bosnia Herzegovina,Formal,Papal Corporation,Franklin Roosevelt,
    29552,Lyndon B. Johnson,Margaret,Palau,Summaries Holdings Inc,Customize,Rutherford B. Hayes,`;

let making_Array = csv => csv
  .split('\n')
  .map(line => line
    .trim()             // 1. trim both ends of the line        
    .replace(/,$/, '')  // 2. remove any last trailing comma
    .split(','))        // 3. split using comma separator
    .map(cols => Object.fromEntries(new Map(header
      .map((colName, index) => [colName, cols[index] || '']))));

console.log(making_Array(string_Data));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is of great help I tried replace too but didn't know where to use it.Thank you

Comment: No problem! If you want to convert the array to some object, take a look at the edit I just posted. Cheers!

Comment: how would you know , its my second step of the program. U r awsome

Answer (score 0):

The empty string is because of the `,` at the end of each line.

You can use the `slice()` method to remove the last element of the array.

```
data.push(dataAry.split(',').slice(0, -1))
```

When you use a negative index as the end of a slice, it counts from the end.

Comment: For reference, the `-1` parameter counts backwards: _Negative index counts back from the end of the array — if end < 0, end + array.length is used_ So in this case, the last element of the array is removed.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove empty strings, but it'll also remove `falsey` values.

`const values = arr.filter(Boolean);`

Comment: Probably not a good idea for a CSV, as it will remove empty values in the middle of the line. That will cause different rows to have different columns.

Comment: that's why we are separating it with \n at first